# Dockerized Solr cannot find requestHandlers

Tags: docker, solr, file-location

I am currently working on a project with a PostgreSQL, Redis, Medusa and Solr implementation.

I want to run all my applications containerized so that I can easily deploy it to my Linux Server.

My issue is that when I try to run a containerized Solr instance from my `docker-compose.yml` it ends up being unable to find the `Request Handlers` I have created.

When I access the admin GUI running on localhost:8983 I am able to see my core and run the `/select` Request Handler.
Inside the GUI when I open my Core (called product_core) under the files I see an entirely different directory.

It seems that I cannot get my Solr instance to find my own solrconfig.xml files even though they're copied to the image.

Which I can see when I `docker exec -it solr /bin/bash` into my Solr instance.

Inside the Solr instance in the directory:`/var/solr/data/product_core`
I can see the files that the GUI shows, but I cannot seem to get it to work to copy the files.

Below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./medusa_backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: dahlfrederik/medusa_backend
    container_name: medusa_backend
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:alpha123@postgres:5432/postgres
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/
      NODE_ENV: development
      JWT_SECRET: some_jwt_secret
      COOKIE_SECRET: some_cookie_secret
      PORT: 9000
      ADMIN_CORS: http://localhost:7000,http://localhost:7001,http://192.168.98.141:7000,http://localhost:7000
      STORE_CORS: http://localhost:3000,http://192.168.98.141:8000,http://localhost:8000
      MEDUSA_DISABLE_TELEMETRY: "true"
    volumes:
      - ./medusa_backend/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    restart: always
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=alpha123
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    expose:
      - 6379
    restart: always
  admin:
    build:
      context: ./medusa_admin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: dahlfrederik/medusa_admin
    container_name: medusa_admin
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      PORT: 7000
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    restart: always
  storefront:
    build:
      context: ./nextjs_frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: dahlfrederik/medusa_storefront
    container_name: storefront
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      PORT: 8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
  solr:
    image: solr
    container_name: solr
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/solr
      - ./solr:/opt/solr/server/solr/product_core
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - product_core
    restart: always
volumes:
  data:
```

My Solr config file are located in the directory Solr which is placed inside the folder containing my docker-compose file.

I have created a `managed-schema.xml` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="default-config" version="1.6">
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="size" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="price" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="image" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
  <field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="false" stored="true" />
  
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
  
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  
  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" />
  
</schema>
```

And I have created a solrconfig.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <requestHandler name="/search" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">100</int>
      <str name="fl">id,title,description,type,size,price,image,inStock</str>
      <str name="facet">true</str>
      <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
      <str name="facet.field">size</str>
      <str name="facet.field">price</str>
      <str name="facet.field">color</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">title^2 description</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>facet</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/autocomplete_search" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="fl">title,image</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
  <searchComponent name="facet">
    <lst name="facet">
      <bool name="facet.sort">true</bool>
      <lst name="facet.field">
        <str name="field">size</str>
        <bool name="facet.missing">true</bool>
        <bool name="facet.sort">false</bool>
        <int name="facet.limit">-1</int>
      </lst>
      <lst name="facet.range">
        <str name="field">price</str>
        <int name="mincount">1</int>
        <str name="method">dv</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="facet.field">
        <str name="field">color</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="fl">id,title,description,type,size,price</str>
      <str name="facet">true</str>
      <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
      <str name="facet.field">size</str>
      <str name="facet.field">price</str>
      <str name="facet.field">color</str>
      
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>facet</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="fieldName">id</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
</config>
```

So it appears that I somehow copy my files to the wrong destination - but when I try to copy it to the one that I can see inside the Solr GUI it does not find my core.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

I tried to change the directory in which the config files are stored.
I've tried docker-compose up --build -d.
Tried changing to use entrypoint instead of command in the docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Which version of solr are you using?

Comment: @Seasers I use the latest image version: 9.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my issues was that the config files was saved at the wrong locations in my docker instance - I figured that out by adding a dummy text file `HelloWorld.txt` and then using Linux search command to find that file and its location.

I solved my problem by adding a script to my Azure build/deployment pipeline that copies the content of my solr-conf folder to my docker instance and then running the reload core command.

So my solution was to run a script that executes following commands:

```
docker cp {path-to-my-solr-config-folder]\solr\conf\. solr:/var/solr/data/{core-name]/conf
```

Then I execute the following post command.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core={core-name}
```

It could probably have been done more intuitively and I am still thinking about adding the commands directly to my `docker-compose.yml` file. But for now this was a way to solve my problem.